# Alter trigger if exists with use of fluent migrator

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger, fluent-migrator

I have one Trigger called dbo.SendMail and multiple database,
not all database have the trigger dbo.SendMail.

I am using FluentMigrator to manage database versions and i want to do something like below

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SendMail]'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SendMail]
    ON [dbo].[Notification]
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        some sql code
    END
END
```

it is giving me error Incorrect syntax near begin, Expecting EXTERNAL.

is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `OBJECT_ID` instead

Comment: You can't quite do this like you are trying. You will either need to check for the existence of trigger and drop it and then always create it, or you would have to use dynamic sql inside your begin to create the trigger.

Comment: @SeanLange but i only wanted recreate trigger if it was previously there

Comment: Then you are going to have to use dynamic sql for your alter statement.

Comment: @SeanLange it would be helpful if you can provide some code examples :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SendMail]', N'TR') IS NOT NULL

-- Do whatever

Else

-- Do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your trigger code with some dynamic sql. You have to roll with dynamic sql here because creating or altering objects must be the only statement in a batch. You can't wrap the create/alter logic inside an IF statement.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SendMail') is not null
begin
    declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
    set @SQL = 'ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SendMail]
    ON [dbo].[Notification]
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        some sql code
    END'

    exec sp_executesql @SQL
end
```